# ERROR - (android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, onclick

Tengo el siguiente codigo para cargar un recyclerview con cardview y en cada cardiew me muestra los empleados a los que se les presto equipo al iniciar el turno al igual que la fecha de el momento en que se carga el recyclerview y le agregue un boton para de esta manera almacenar la fecha en que el empleado devolvio el equipo prestado. Pero al momento de loguearme no me carga el fragment con mi recyclerview y me muestra el siguiente error

`(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo de mi fragment donde tengo el recycler es el siguiente

HomeFragment.java

```
package com.xcheko51x.buscadorrecyclerviewmysql.ui.home;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{

    private MenuItem menuItem;
    private SearchView searchView;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    RecyclerView recyclerUsuarios;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;
    Button btnActualizar;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TextView txtentrega,txtid;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    // RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    StringRequest stringRequest;//SE MODIFICA



    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        txtentrega= (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtsalida);
        txtid= (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.emid);
        btnActualizar= (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnexit);

        listaUsuarios=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerUsuarios= (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerUsuarios.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        cargarWebService();

        //eventos botones
        btnActualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                webServiceActualizar();
            }
        });

        return vista;

    }

    private void cargarWebService() {

        progress=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.setMessage("Consultando...");
        progress.show();

        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/wsJSONConsultarLista.php";

        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        
        // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    private void webServiceActualizar() {
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.show();

        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/wsJSONUpdateMovil.php?";

        stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                pDialog.hide();

                if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("actualiza")){
                    // etiNombre.setText("");
                    //  txtDocumento.setText("");
                    //   etiProfesion.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Se ha Actualizado con exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha Actualizado ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("RESPUESTA: ",""+response);
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha podido conectar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                String idem=txtid.getText().toString();
                String salida=txtentrega.getText().toString();

                Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<>();
                parametros.put("fecha_sal",salida);
                parametros.put("idem",idem);

                return parametros;
            }
        };
        
        //request.add(stringRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se puede conectar "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
        progress.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Usuario usuario=null;

        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("usuario");

        try {

            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                usuario=new Usuario();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

                usuario.setId(jsonObject.optString("Id"));
                usuario.setReloj(jsonObject.optString("reloj"));
                usuario.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));
                usuario.setArea(jsonObject.optString("area"));
                usuario.setEquipo(jsonObject.optString("equipo"));
                usuario.setFecha(jsonObject.optString("fecha_ent"));
                listaUsuarios.add(usuario);
            }
            progress.hide();
            UsuariosAdapter adapter=new UsuariosAdapter(listaUsuarios);
            recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido establecer conexión con el servidor" +
                    " "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.hide();
        }

    }
    
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Este error me lo muestra en el siguiente metodo

```
//eventos botones
        btnActualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                webServiceActualizar();
            }
        });
```

De igual manera hace referencia un error secundario hacia el Main
`ActivityNavigationBinding.inflate(ActivityNavigationBinding.java:48)`

NavigationActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityNavigationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarNavigation.toolbar);
        binding.appBarNavigation.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_list,R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_navigation);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
```

El error hace referencia a la siguiente seccion del metodo onCreate

```
binding = ActivityNavigationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Anexo imagen del sistema cuando quito el codigo del boton actualizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

usuarios_list.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvTarjeta"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="177dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="149dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtArea"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Area"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtEquipo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Equipo"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtFecha"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Fecha"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtReloj"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="ID"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Nombre"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SmallSp" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="276dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="22dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtsalida"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="Salida"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="Hora de Retorno"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/emid"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:hint="ID"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnexit"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="34dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Salida"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Muestra el XML del layout ligado a `HomeFragment`, al parecer en ese layout no está el botón con id `btnexit`, por otra parte, si usas Data o View Binding, no deberías usar `findViewById`, sino referirte a los elementos directamente por medio de `binding.elId`

Comment: Listo agregue los 2 xml que utilizo para el recycler view y el cardview

Comment: Ya, pero es que si el botón se repite en todos los items del RecyclerView, el evento onClick no debe ir en el fragmento, sino en el Adapter del RecyclerView. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49969278/5587982) y sus respuestas para más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

El error es causado por dos razones:

1)No obtienes la referencia de la vista a la cual deseas configurar el listener.

2)Obtienes la referencia de la vista, pero esta no existe en el layout que que supone contener la vista.

En este caso por ejemplo, se debe encontrar la vista con id `btnexit` dentro del layout `fragment_home.xml`:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ...
        ...
        btnActualizar= (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnexit);
        ... 
        ...
        btnActualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        ...
        ...
```

si revisas el layout, este no contiene la vista con id `btnexit` , por esta razón no puede obtener la referencia de la vista y se genera el error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment" >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Oh entiendo ahora mi pregunta es no causaria problema por que el boton esta declarado en el layout del recyclerview '(usuarios_list.xml)' ahi esta el boton que esta junto con el cardview de igual manera deja lo intento como me comentas haber si me funciona